# optimize nested for loops within nested if statements

Tags: java, performance

I am trying to optimize this code. The only optimization I can think of is to ?¿? a `return` or `break` statement after `applyOfferChanges(…)` inside the second `if` condition which does not work either because there could be multiple matches. I cannot either use a map for `favoriteMerchantsList` because `getFavoriteMerchantsList()` return type is a list (of favorited merchants). Any ideas?

```
void applyFavoriteChangesToMerchantStore(){

    List<Merchant> favoriteMerchantsList = FavoriteMerchantStore.getInstance().getFavoriteMerchantsList();
    if(favoriteMerchantsList != null && !favoriteMerchantsList.isEmpty()) {
        List<Merchant> storeMerchantList = MerchantStore.getInstance().getMerchantList();
        for (Merchant storeMerchant : storeMerchantList) {
            for (Merchant favoriteMerchant: favoriteMerchantsList){
                if(TextUtils.equals(storeMerchant.getId(), favoriteMerchant.getId())){
                    //merchant match found
                    //set merchant favorite status

                   storeMerchant.setFavoriteMerchant(favoriteMerchant.getFavoriteMerchant());
                    //set offer favorite status
                    applyOfferChanges(favoriteMerchant.getOffferList(),
                            storeMerchant.getOffferList());
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to [codereview.se]! Please provide additional code which forms a complete program so that reviewers can run and test your code.

Comment: Please edit the question title to say _what your code achieves_ instead of _what you want to be done to your code_.

Comment: Please add some details about how many favorite and store merchants there are usually. And what ahould happen if there are multiple matches.

Comment: Interesting information would be also: What is a "Merchant" and what is the relationship between a "store merchant" and a "favorite merchant"? Why do they use the same class, but need to matched like that?

Comment: Furthermore, please define "optimize". In terms of runtime? (Is there a concrete problem?) In terms of readability? In terms of less lines of code?

Answer (score 4):

You are implementing an inner join as a nested loop join. There are several other ways to implement joins, such as hash-based or sort-merge sort. Which one is better depends on the length of the lists.

I will sketch a hash join as that usually works most of the time.

```
void applyFavoriteChangesToMerchantStore(){

    List<Merchant> favoriteMerchantsList = FavoriteMerchantStore.getInstance().getFavoriteMerchantsList();
    if(favoriteMerchantsList != null && !favoriteMerchantsList.isEmpty()) {
        // build the hash table
        Map<String, Merchant> favoriteMerchantById = favoriteMerchantsList.stream().collect(Collectors.toMap(Merchant::getId, Function.identity()));
        List<Merchant> storeMerchantList = MerchantStore.getInstance().getMerchantList();
        for (Merchant storeMerchant : storeMerchantList) {
            // probe the hash table
            Merchant favoriteMerchant = favoriteMerchantById.get(storeMerchant.getId())
            if(favoriteMerchant != null){
                //merchant match found
                //set merchant favorite status

               storeMerchant.setFavoriteMerchant(favoriteMerchant.getFavoriteMerchant());
                //set offer favorite status
                applyOfferChanges(favoriteMerchant.getOffferList(),
                        storeMerchant.getOffferList());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I assumed that `TextUtils.equals` is equal to `String.equals`. If it's more lenient (e.g., case-insensitive), you need to normalize the lookup key (e.g., `String.toLowerCase()`).